# How to use regex rules to match string?

Tags: python, regex, search-engine

I am trying to make more use of regEx in my search engine. Please take a look :

```
someStr = "Processor AMD Athlon II X4 651K BOX Black Edition, s. FM1, 3.0GHz, 4MB cache, Quad Core"

# THIS SHOULD MATCH / processors-plural with 0 to 1,
# mega or mb should be the same
# and quad with 0 to 2 of any characters except whitespace
queryListTrue = ["processors", "amd", "4mega", "quaddy"]

# THIS SHOULDN'T MATCH / bad last item length
queryListFalse = ["processors", "amd", "4mb", "quaddie"]

# TO DESCRIBE WHAT I NEED
rulesList = [ r'processor[i.e. 0-1 char]', r'amd',
            r'4mega or 4mb', r'quad[from 0 to 2 any char]' ]

if ALL queryListTrue MATCHES someStr THRU rulesList : 
        print "What a wonderful world!"
```

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Using regex to do black magic?

Comment: I already made it by simple comparing and I thought that regex is more powerful!? ...but forgot about loop, that's easy part but list of expressions bothers me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression for "[from 0 to 1 any char]" is simply

```
.?
```

i.e. dot `.` matches any character (except newline, by default) and the `?` quantifier means the preceding expression is optional.

Note that `processor.?` will also match a space after `processor` or an arbitrary character such as `processord`.  You probably intend `processors?` where the plural `s` is optional, or perhaps `processor[a-z]?`  to constrain the optional last character to an alphabetic character.

Similarly, the generalized quantifier `{m,n}` specifies "at least *m* repetitions and at most *n* repetitions", so your "[from 0 to 2 any char]" translated to regex is `.{0,2}`.

Alternation in regular expressions is specified with `|` so `mega|mb` is the regex formulation for your "mega or mb".  If you use the alternation in a longer context where some of the text is not subject to alternation, you need to add parentheses to scope the alternation, like `m(ega|b)`.

In Python (like in most modern Perl-derived regex dialects), you can use `(?:` instead of `(` if the grouping behavior of regular parentheses is undesired.

Comment: Upvote for this excellent explanation and also accepted. Besides I edited mb/mega to 4mb/4mega to be more clear, but I got the picture. Much obliged.